# Jquery event not firing for a button created in javascript with innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I search around the web but cant do this work..

Im creating a dialog in a js.file . In this js i have a function that creates a button, but with innerHTML...

```
    var divButtons = document.getElementById('buttons_insert1');    
    var buttons_insert = "<button id='okcad' class='button_ok' value='' > <img src='/php/Images/OK.png' alt='OK' /> OK </button>";
    divButtons.innerHTML = divButtons.innerHTML + buttons_insert;
```

and in the index.html i have a jquery function to get the click event.

```
$("#okcad1").click(function() 
{
   alert('hello world');
}
```

but this is not working..the event dont fire...

Someone could help me?

Regards!

Rafael S.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `event delegation`

```
$(document).on("click" , "#buttons_insert1 #okcad1" , function() 
{
   alert('hello world');
});
```

Comment: @downvoters care to comment

Comment: Thanks Amit and JqueryKing! But only the JQueryKing answer worked...can u tell me why? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for this. I used the javascript equivalent and it worked perfect. Rafael, I suspect that Amit's answer is assigning the event to the wrong element.

Answer (score 2):

You need event-delegation, since you're appending it after DOM has been loaded. For that use [`jQuery.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on)

```
$("#buttons_insert1").on('click', '#okcad1', function() {
   alert('hello world');
}
```

Just `click` will bind the event to the elements which were present in the DOM when the code got executed, so you need the technique of event-delegation.